# Multiplication table in JavaScript - 2 tables

Tags: javascript, html, multiplication

I'm, starting to learn javascript and I have a problem with this code. The code asks for two numbers (the first must be lower than the second) and then it shows the multiplication from the first to the second number. If you type 5 and 7, it shows the multiplication of 5, 6 and 7.

The problem comes when the second number is typed is 10 (except if you type 1 and 10, it shows all). If I type 2 and 10  it shows nothing.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
function multiply() {
do {
  do {
    var i1 = prompt("Type first number from 1 to 10", "");
  } while (i1 < 1 || i1 > 10);

  do {
    var i2 = prompt("Type second number from 1 to 10 (number must be higher than the first one", "");
  } while (i2 < 1 || i2 > 10);

  var check = i2 - i1;

  if (check >= 0) {
    for (var i = i1; i <= i2 ; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      document.write("<br>" + i + " x " + j + " = " +  i * j);
        }
    document.write("<p>" );
    }
  } else {
    alert("First number is higher than the second, PLease try again.")
    }

} while (check < 0)
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Just a tip to improve the code. You can remove the outermost do-while and add a call to `multiply()` in your else statement below the `alert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return-value of `prompt ()` is a string. So you need to `parseInt()` to get integers.

```js
do {
  do {
    var i1 = parseInt (prompt("Type first number from 1 to 10", ""));
  } while (i1 < 1 || i1 > 10);

  do {
    var i2 = parseInt (prompt("Type second number from 1 to 10 (number must be higher than the first one", ""));
  } while (i2 < 1 || i2 > 10);

  var check = i2 - i1;

  if (check >= 0) {
    for (var i = i1; i <= i2 ; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      document.write("<br>" + i + " x " + j + " = " +  i * j);
        }
    document.write("<p>" );
    }
  } else {
    alert("First number is higher than the second, PLease try again.")
    }

} while (check < 0)
```